# Storing floating point numbers into the EEPROM on an ESP32 can this be done

Tags: arduino-esp32, eeprom

I have been trying to store 2 floating point numbers into the EEPROM only if there values have been changed during the ESP32 normal operations. This will happen just before a automated reboot of the ESP32. I can do it with integers no problem. So far I am finding hard to get information on doing it with Floats.

My code is very here so far

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include <Secret.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>


#define MQTT_HOST "192.168.0.30"  // MQTT Broker IP Address
#define MQTT_PORT 1883            // MQTT Broker Port


const char* MQTT_PUB_TEMP = "backupHeaterControl"; // Temperature MQTT Topic
const char* MQTT_PUB_HEAT = "backupHeaterStatus";  // Heater Status MQTT Topic
const int oneWireBus = 4;
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
unsigned long thenMillis = 0;
const long interval = 10000;
const long interval1 = 15000;
float temp = 0.0;
float minTempThreshold = 24.6;
float maxTempThreshold = 25.0;

const int heaterPin = 23;

// These are used for the storing of the EEPROM only when the variables have been changed.
unsigned long restartTimer = 86400000; // 28 day reset timer 2419200000
float lastMinTempThreshold = minTempThreshold;  // Track last-written values
float lastMaxTempThreshold = maxTempThreshold;

OneWire oneWire(oneWireBus);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient mqttClient(espClient);

void espRebootTimer() {
  if ((millis() % restartTimer) < 2000) {
    if (minTempThreshold != lastMinTempThreshold || maxTempThreshold != lastMaxTempThreshold) {
      EEPROM.write(0, int(minTempThreshold ));
      EEPROM.write(1, int(maxTempThreshold ));
      EEPROM.commit();
      EEPROM.begin(512);
      lastMinTempThreshold = minTempThreshold;
      lastMaxTempThreshold = maxTempThreshold;
    }
    ESP.restart();
  }
}

void restoreFromEEPROM() {
  minTempThreshold = float(EEPROM.read(0));
  maxTempThreshold = float(EEPROM.read(1));
  lastMinTempThreshold = minTempThreshold;
  lastMaxTempThreshold = maxTempThreshold;
}

void connectToWifi() {
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
}

void connectToMqtt() {
  while (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    if (mqttClient.connect("ESP8266Client")) {
      Serial.println("Connected to MQTT broker");
      mqttClient.subscribe("backupMaxSetting");
      mqttClient.subscribe("backupMinSetting");
    } else {
      Serial.print("Failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(mqttClient.state());
      Serial.println(" retrying in 5 seconds");
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void WiFiEvent(WiFiEvent_t event) {
  switch (event) {
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP:
      connectToMqtt();
      break;
    case SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_DISCONNECTED:
      connectToWifi();
      break;
  }
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  sensors.begin();
  EEPROM.begin(512);
  float storedMinTemp = EEPROM.read(0);
  float storedMaxTemp = EEPROM.read(1);

  if (storedMinTemp == 0xFF && storedMaxTemp == 0xFF) {

    EEPROM.write(0, minTempThreshold);
    EEPROM.write(1, maxTempThreshold);
    EEPROM.commit();
}   else {
      minTempThreshold = storedMinTemp;
      maxTempThreshold = storedMaxTemp;
}
 
  restoreFromEEPROM();
  pinMode(2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(heaterPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(heaterPin, HIGH);

  Serial.println(minTempThreshold);
  Serial.println(maxTempThreshold);

  WiFi.onEvent(WiFiEvent);
  connectToWifi();

  mqttClient.setServer(MQTT_HOST, MQTT_PORT);
  mqttClient.setCallback(onMqttMessage);

  
}

void controlHeater() {
  if (temp <= minTempThreshold) {
    digitalWrite(2, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(heaterPin, LOW);
  } else if (temp >= maxTempThreshold) {
    digitalWrite(2, LOW);
    digitalWrite(heaterPin, HIGH);
  }
}

void publishHeaterStatus() {
  if (digitalRead(heaterPin) == LOW) {
    mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_HEAT, "Heater On");
  } else {
    mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_HEAT, "Heater Off");
  }
}

void onMqttMessage(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  if (strcmp(topic, "backupMaxSetting") == 0) {
    payload[length] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the payload
    float newMaxTemp = atof((const char*)payload);
    maxTempThreshold = newMaxTemp;
    Serial.print("Updated maxTempThreshold to: ");
    Serial.println(maxTempThreshold);

    // Send a return message with the updated setting
    char returnMessage[50]; // Adjust the size as needed
    snprintf(returnMessage, sizeof(returnMessage), "New maxTempThreshold: %.2f", maxTempThreshold);
    mqttClient.publish("feedbackTopic", returnMessage);
  }
  if (strcmp(topic, "backupMinSetting") == 0) {
    payload[length] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the payload
    float newMinTemp = atof((const char*)payload);
    minTempThreshold = newMinTemp;
    Serial.print("Updated minTempThreshold to: ");
    Serial.println(minTempThreshold);

    // Send a return message with the updated setting
    char returnMessage[50]; // Adjust the size as needed
    snprintf(returnMessage, sizeof(returnMessage), "New minTempThreshold: %.2f", minTempThreshold);
    mqttClient.publish("feedbackTopic", returnMessage);
  }
}

void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    previousMillis = currentMillis;
    sensors.requestTemperatures();
    temp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
    mqttClient.publish(MQTT_PUB_TEMP, String(temp).c_str());
  }

  if (currentMillis - thenMillis >= interval1) {
    thenMillis = currentMillis;
    publishHeaterStatus();
  }

  controlHeater();

  if (!mqttClient.connected()) {
    connectToMqtt();
  }
  mqttClient.loop();
  espRebootTimer();
}
```

The main reason for the storing is I am concerned with any effect of using the millis() and the fact that it could effect the sketch when the millis() over flows.

Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: I have seen that a preference library maybe the way to go or use bytes to break down the values and save them instead and the convert after restart. lots more reading to be done.

Comment: A possible solution was shown here. [link] https://onecompiler.com/c/3zj8hxymz?fbclid=IwAR281QvHFRW0SsB9sGrJuYbGRQjbm2K0JtUHUnGxS_hEDttR2n4MTSJp_Oc [/link]

Comment: 1) There is quite a misunderstanding of millis() and its overflow here, you are using the millis() as `millis() - previousMillis` (both values are unsigned long, i.e. uint32_t) in a very short interval, even when the millis() is overflowed, it does not create any issue whatsoever, and certain do not need to reboot your system.

Comment: 2) By DallasTemperature, if you means you are using sensor such as DS18B20, the temperature data from the sensor is actually represented as an integer with 1/16 precision and can be read with [getTemp()](https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library/blob/master/DallasTemperature.h#L162) function, so you can transport and store data in integer instead of floating point, and only need to be coverted to float when printing to display the actual temperature, For DS18B20, for example, 25.0625 degree celsius is read as raw data as 0x191 (i.e. 401) and 401/16=20.0625.

Comment: 3) Single precision floating point value in computer is store as 4-byte data defined in [IEEE754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754).

Comment: Thanks hcheung I thought it may cause an issue with rollover as the previous number would have been a lot larger  than when it rolled over so instead of say 60 second for the next check it could take upto 50 days to reach the trigger time.

Comment: Thanks hcheung Yes the data is from a ds18b20 which in the code does get converted to a float.  Its been tested for the last few weeks and I have a work around which is to use Node red to resent a value of 24.5 after a reboot. I could live with a 1 Deg C change in temperature as well. I did try doing a few different methods of converting the float to a an in before updating the EEPROM and then convert it back to a float on restart.

Comment: I will also look at the IEEE754 to see if that makes sense and I can use the information I learn from that page.